# Programmatically Lock and unlock Screen of iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Can we programmatically lock and unlock Screen of the iPhone?

Is it possible or is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically lock and unlock iPhone screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-iphone-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not allowed on non jailbroke iPhones. There may be a private API for it but apple would reject an app using it.

Comment: No problem. As a note, you will get more answers if you go back and mark more of your questions as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES
```

This will not lock your device when app is running on device.
But you cant Lock and Unlock device programmatically.