# Regarding iphone application i-OS-4.0

Tags: iphone

How to lock and unlock iphone screen using programm??

Regrds
Lipika

Comment: In general, you cannot do anything programmatically that takes control of the device away from the user and any function that does so is automatically a non-starter and Apple blocks it.  How would having apps lock the screen empower the user? If a user wants the screen locked they can already lock it themselves at any time.

Comment: Not to mention the possible mischief that could result from locking and unlocking the phone without the user's knowledge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically Lock and unlock Screen of iPhone .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-screen-of-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

that is not possible.
Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-screen-of-iphone/833223#833223) by [Mugunth Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90165/mugunth-kumar).

Comment: lol. this is hilarious... "I will not answer your question here on Stackoverflow if you ask anything about Iphone or IPHONE or I-phone." Good one!