# Can you activate the iPhone lock screen from code or push notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, locking, screen, push-notification

I've a client who is suggesting that you can activate the iPhone lock screen from code. His idea is to send a push notification and lock the phone that way.

I don't think this is possible (for practical reasons mostly).

Am I correct?

Comment: There is some discussion on this similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-screen-of-iphone

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question itself. **It is not possible**. You can prevent your phone from locking when your app is running.

Code as,

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES
```