# How to lock the iPhone screen programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can my iOS program lock the iPhone's screen?

Comment: A quick scan through the developer guidelines doesn't specifically mention this behavior, but that doesn't mean it's not against the rules.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-iphone-screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: So one can disable the automatic screen lock and implement his/hers own scheme?