# Lock iphone home screen from my app

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to lock the device home screen programatically from my app. Is it possible in IOS?

In my app, if the user is idle for 1 minute, i want to lock the device. This is the scenario.

Thanks
Jithen

Comment: you mean if user one minute idle then from home scren any thing not enable to go inside right??

Comment: No, If user is in my app and if user kept the device idle in my app, then i want to lock the phone after 1 minute.

Comment: You can't... Public API doesn't allow this :)

Comment: [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES, this too wont work? Paras said it works..

Comment: NO... if you setIdleTimerDisabled:YES, it will even disable screen lock timer set in device settings. Your task is actually to lock it after one minute

Comment: This has been discussed in detail here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-iphone-screen

Answer (score 1):

you can lock the phone using bellow code

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Comment: then try this     [[ UIApplication sharedApplication ] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES ];

Comment: where you try this code?? means in timer after 1 minute this method or this code call ??

Comment: @ParasJoshi, Jithen wants to lock screen after one minute and if you setIdleTimerDisabled:YES, it will even disable screen lock timer set in device settings.

Comment: then see this answer may you can get some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-iphone-screen i hope this help you

Comment: This piece of code does not do what you are suggesting.
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES; 
will keep your phone from going into the locked state on its own while your app is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock your own App by Adding a block view on Appdelegate's window. But locking your device is the responsibility of OS. I think if you somehow implement this then still aplle might reject your app on it. [image]